# CGAL arrangements: how to parse the faces inside a hole?

Tags: cgal

Let's take Figure 34.2 of [the user manual](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Arrangement_on_surface_2/index.html). `f1` contains two holes. When parsing the holes using `f1->holes_begin()` and `f1->holes_end()`, how can I get the list of the faces inside each hole? For example, from the hole "f3+f4", how can I get the list (f3, f4)?

Of course, I could iterate over all the halfedges bounding the hole and access the face it bounds on its interior side using the `twin()` to get the opposite halfedge, and then `face()` to get the face that the opposite halfedge bounds, then remove duplicates, but I'm wondering if there is a simpler solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over the ccbs. For example, the code in `draw_arrangement_2.h` does it; see an explanation below.
Observe that the face member functions `holes_begin()` and `holes_end()` are the same as  `inner_ccbs_begin()` and `inner_ccbs_end()`. (The latter come from the base class `Arrangement_on_syrface_2`.)

We maintain a Boolean flag for each face called `m_visited` that indicates whether we visited the face. In the code this is done via an `std:unordered_map`. You can also extend the face record with a Boolean flag for instance.

We start with the unbounded faces (see `add_faces()`) and descend down to their holes. For each face `f` we call `add_face(f)`; in this function we traverse the face inner ccbs and outer ccbs. For each ccb `c` we call `add_ccb(c)`. For a ccb `c` we traverse the halfedges of `c`; for each halfedge `h` we visit the face `f` incident to the twin of `h`. If we visited `f` we discard it; otherwise, we mark it as visited and recurse to process `f` by calling `add_face(f)`.

Notice that in the drawing function we process the ccbs such that we draw the regions bounded by the outer ccb of the faces in the opposite order of containment; see the call to `draw_region()`.

Comment: Thank you for confirming there is no direct way to get the faces. I ended up doing something very similar to what you describe.